# What's wrong with my switching function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script, part of which is similar to below:

```
function FooBarMeh ($in,$1,$2)
{
    switch($in)
    {
        $1{'FOO'}
        $2{'BAR'}
        default{'MEH'}
    }
}
$a='A'
$b='B'
$c=read-host
FooBarMeh ($c,$a,$b)
```

I expect the script to return `FOO` if I enter `A`, `BAR` if I enter `B`, and `MEH` if I enter anything else.

However, this is what actually happens:

[image]

No matter what I input, I get `MEH` returned to me three times. If I was to expect `MEH` at all - even if my first two switching options were somehow broken - I'd think I should only see it once. Why am I getting `MEH` at all, let alone three times?

Using PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use parentheses when you call functions in PowerShell. You should call FooBarMeh like this:

```
FooBarMeh $c $a $b
```

If you call it with `($c, $a, $b)`, then you are passing an array of 3 elements. That array gets assigned to `$in`.

(It's interesting that the switch acts like a loop. It gets executed for each item in the array. I wasn't expecting that.)

Note however when you call .NET functions you do use parentheses. For example:

```
$a.Contains('A')
```

Comment: I should have known better. This serves just as well too, since the problem I'm solving is for code golf anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Iszi, you're welcome. I'm sure most of us have made that mistake at least once.